# net client receives it's own data when writing to port

Tags: node.js, sockets

I've a simple Socket Client written in nodejs using the native "net" library.

Every time I send a message to the server, the client receives a on('data') event with it's own message.

Is it possible to avoid this type of loopback?
I only care about messages coming from the socket server and not my own messages.

```
var client = new net.Socket();

// 1. Connect
client.connect(10000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connection to net Server successful');
    client.write('Hello, server! I just connected to you.'); // <--this...
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received for server: ' + data); // <--...will fire in here
});
```

Here is the log output coming as a result of the above code execution.

```
Connection to net Server successful
Received from server: Echo server 
// ^ This came from the socket server.
Received from server: Hello, server! I just connected to you. 
// ^ This is wrong, since this is what I sent to the socket server.
```

Comment: Since you are recieving a message *Echo server* i guess it does exactly what it should. *Echo server* usually returns whatever you send it.

Comment: Can you share your server code?